# Vim key binding to cycle through windows

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I bind one single key to cycle through the windows? For example, each time I want to switch a window, I have to click <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> (default was <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>) then use arrow key up/down/left/right to switch. Can I have just one key that does <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> + switching the window? I was thinking to bind it with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, but I couldn't resolve the issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a key binding as you would do for any other command. Here I present one mapping for normal mode and one mapping for insert mode, both using <kbd>tab</kbd>.

```
nnoremap <tab> :wincmd w<cr>
inoremap <tab> <c-o>:wincmd w<cr>
```

For more information and inspiration for further custimization see [`:h wincmd`.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3awincmd)